# Is there a reserved word for datetime for the start of the day?

Tags: date

`man date` won't show me any reserved words but they have 'now' or 'today' etc.

I wonder if there is any clear way to print start(00:00:00) of the day.

Will `date -u -d "$(date +'%F')"` suffice in any situation? Looks a little dumb.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`date -d 00:00` or `date -d 00:00:00` work with the GNU, ast-open, toybox and busybox implementations of `date`.

`date -d 0` also works with GNU `date`.

```
$ date -d 00:00
Tue  4 Oct 00:00:00 BST 2022
```

With BSD `date`:

```
$ date -jf %H%M%S 000000
Mon Oct  4 00:00:00 BST 2022
```

None of `-j`, `-f`, `-d` are standard option to `date`.

[POSIX `date`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/date.html) has no provision for specifying an input date other than now except for setting the system clock (under the XSI option).

You could do:

```
$ date '+%a %e 00:00:00 %Z %Y'
Tue  4 00:00:00 BST 2022
```

But the `BST` part can end up being wrong if you run that on the day the clock changes from/to winter time.

`ksh93` and `zsh` have builtin support for parsing input dates:

- ksh93

  ```
  $ printf '%(%c [%s epoch time])T\n' 00:00
  Tue Oct  4 00:00:00 2022 [1664838000 epoch time]
  ```

  (`bash` copied the `%(format)T` from ksh93 but not the ability to specify input dates other than in epoch seconds).

  ksh93 can also be built with the ast-open `date` builtin.
- zsh

  ```
  $ zmodload zsh/datetime
  $ strftime -s today %F
  $ strftime -rs start %F $today
  $ strftime '%c [%s epoch time]' $start
  Tue 04 Oct 2022 00:00:00 BST [1664838000 epoch time]
  ```

  Or getting today's date using prompt expansion (here via the `%` parameter expansion flag):

  ```
  $ zmodload zsh/datetime
  $ strftime -rs start %F ${(%):-%D{%F}}
  $ strftime '%c [%s epoch time]' $start
  Tue 04 Oct 2022 00:00:00 BST [1664838000 epoch time]
  ```

---

Note that your:

> ```
> date -u -d "$(date +'%F')"
> ```

Takes today's date in **your** timezone in YYYY-MM-DD format, but then asks `date` to give you the time for 00:00:00 **UTC** on that day, which unless you're in a timezone that currently happens to align with UTC will not be the start of *your* day.

Here in mainland Britain which is still in summer time (one hour ahead of UTC):

```
$ date -u -d "$(date +'%F')" +%s
1664841600
$ date -d 00:00 +%s
1664838000
```

Comment: the GNU date also accepts things such as "today" ("yesterday" & "tomorrow" work too) as an input string and thus you could be more explicit by using an expression such as:-
date -d "today 00:00:00" +"%F %T %Z"; this would have a more explicit intention for later maintainers (including yourself, days or years later).

Comment: @MNB, yes though, it's a lot less portable. Also beware of `TZ=Europe/London faketime 2022-10-30T00:01 date -d tomorrow +%F` returning 2022-10-30 with current versions of GNU `date`.

Comment: agreed on the lower portability. Also that is an interesting bug, is that due to the BST to GMT transition in the early hours of the 30th October?

Comment: @MNB, IIRC GNU `date` has put some thought into those DST issues, so it may work as intended and documented, I'd have to look again in the doc and source to check.

Comment: @MNB, yes, see `info date 'Relative items in date strings'`. `tomorrow` is the same as `1 day` or `day` and a `day` is 24 hours of 3600 seconds, not a calendar day.

Comment: Having said that `TZ=Europe/London faketime 2022-10-30T00:01 date -d 'tomorrow 00:00:00' +%FT%T%z` returns `2022-10-31T00:00:00+0000`.